# 2-3 tree - difficulty with splitting

Tags: java, tree

My assignment is to create a 2-3 tree.  I have done all of the necessary classes and methods that are required, but I am having difficulty with my *split* method.  I am probably overthinking this way too much, and my head is just spinning and I can't seem to get myself out of the train of thought that I have gotten myself into.

If I was only required to just split a leaf node, I would not have a problem.  Where my mind seems to be stuck is where I have to split a leaf node, then split the parent above.  From what I understand, the disconnecting of children, then splitting, then connecting of children will all differ based on which child is originally being split.

i.e. if I have the following tree, my first split occurs in the leaf node (say the third child of the second child of the root the 13 |14).  This split process would be habdled differently than say the the fist child of the third child of the root (19 | 20).

```
                                            9 |18
           3 |  6                          12 | 15                          21 | 24
 1 |  2    4 |  5    7 |  8      10 | 11   13 | 14   16 | 17      19 | 20   22 | 23   25 |26
```

The part of my split method that I am having problems with is:

```
    if (upperRight != null)
    {
        if (childIndex == 0)
        {
            parent.connectChild(1, newRight);
            newRight.connectChild(0, child1);
            newRight.connectChild(1, child2);
        }
        else if (childIndex == 1)
        {
            upperRight.connectChild(0, newRight);
        }
        else if (childIndex == 2)
        {
            upperRight.connectChild(0, newRight);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Node temp = parent.disconnectChild(1);
        parent.connectChild(1, newRight);
        parent.connectChild(2, temp);

        if (childIndex == 0)
        {
            temp = newRight.disconnectChild(0);
            newRight.connectChild(0, child1);
            newRight.connectChild(1, child2);
            newRight.connectChild(2, temp);
        }
        else if (childIndex == 1)
        {
            thisNode.connectChild(1, child1);
            newRight.connectChild(1, child2);
        }
        else if (childIndex == 2)
        {
            temp = newRight.disconnectChild(0);
            thisNode.connectChild(1, child1);
            newRight.connectChild(0, child2);
            newRight.connectChild(1, temp);
        }
    }
    return newRight;
```

If anyone could help direct me as to how to think about this differently I would appreciate it.  The output that I am receiving either has my children in the incorrect order or somewhere I am overwriting some children or both.

Answer (score 0):

The technique of using a four node to help do the splitting is discussed in [Balanced Search Trees](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/33balanced/) of Algorithms by Robert Sedgwich.